Tire Size Question
My bicycle rims are 26", my tires are 26x2.00. I am having hard time finding 2.00" cheap tires for a mountain bike. Can I change tires to a 2.10 which, seems to offered a lot on certain websites? I ride maybe 5 times a year on pavements, grass, occasional woods (nothing major). I am looking for a cheap tire around $40-$50 a piece. Also have a question about tubes vs tubeless. My current tires have tubes in them. Do I need a specific tire that will take a tube?
Sorry for all the questions just got a used mountain bike and tires and tubes are shot. Want to go for a short ride this weekend(Memorial Day) if I can but want to order the tires asap. Any recommendations is appreciated!!!

Please don't put your email address in the question. Putting it in your profile is just fine however.

2.1" should fit. Refer This question

Your bike will have tubed tyres, so you need a tube for each wheel.  The tube is what holds the air pressure.   If they're not building air pressure, then the tube has a hole and needs patching or replacing.
If the tyres are falling apart then they need replacing.
The replacement tube should have the same valve as the old ones, probably a "schrader" or car-style.  Tube will have to be a 26 inch which is also "559" in the metric system.
A replacement tyre also has to be the same overall diameter as the existing tyre, but the width can vary a little as long as it doesn't hit anything on the frame while turning.   You need 5 to 10mm of space between tyre and frame to allow for mud and flex.
Avoid anything that says "tubeless" because your bike likely doesn't have that.
